# Concatenate control attributes when some === "undefined"

Tags: jquery

I need to create a querystring that consists of attribute values of an `<input type="text" ...` form control. It's possible some of the attributes might not exist and so I am testing for `"undefined"` but not getting the expected result.

```
var ctl = $('#somecontrol');

var url = "/someuri/" +
    "?pid=" + ctl.attr('id') +
    "&m=" + (typeof ctl.attr('mid') === "undefined") ? "" : ctl.attr('mid') +
    "&u=" + (typeof ctl.attr('uid') === "undefined") ? "" : ctl.attr('uid') +
    "&dvalue=" + (typeof ctl.attr('value') === "undefined") ? "" : ctl.attr('value') +
    "&dchoice=" + (typeof ctl.val() === "undefined") ? "" : ctl.val();
```

Some of the attributes can be undefined at times and defined at others. If I remove the ternary logic and just include the `ctl.attr('...') +` the url variable is okay except that it will contain `undefined` for undefined attributes.

Including the ternary logic always leaves url as an empty string (`""`).

What am I doing wrong with the `var url =` line?

Comment: can you show the html of the input you're talking about?

Comment: First of all, wrap whole `(typeof ctl.attr('mid') === "undefined") ? "" : ctl.attr('measureid')` code chunks with additional `()`. Secondly, `typeof ctl.attr('mid') === "undefined"` can simply be `ctl.attr('mid') === undefined`. Thirdly, avoid a lot of duplicate code by moving this ternary operation to separate function.

Comment: As @Regent pointed out, the issue here is operator precendence. For example, `1 ? 1 : 3 + 1` evaluates to `1` instead of `2`.

Comment: @Regent I followed both of your suggestions and the problem is resolved. If you would post an answer I can mark it as the answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Regent I removed the quotes around `undefined` but then undefined attributes were showing up in the querystring with `"undefined"` again. I added the quotes back and it is working correctly now.

Comment: @rwkiii you're welcome. Most probably you forgot to remove `typeof`.

Comment: @rwkiii you also have strange places: checking for `ctl.attr('mid')`, but setting `ctl.attr('measureid')`. Is it normal behaviour?

Comment: @Regent no. I was trying to shorten the code for the question and forgot that bit. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important thing:

- `(typeof ctl.attr('mid') === "undefined") ? "" : ctl.attr('measureid')` and other similar code chunks should be wrapped with additional `()`

Additional thing:

- `typeof ctl.attr('mid') === "undefined"` can simply be `ctl.attr('mid') === undefined`

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/e659xs75/).

**Update**.
Second additional thing to avoid code duplication by using additional `function`:

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/e659xs75/1/).

```
var ctl = $('#somecontrol');

var url = "/someuri/" +
        "?pid=" + ctl.attr('id') +
        "&m=" + formValue(ctl.attr('mid')) +
        "&u=" + formValue(ctl.attr('uid')) +
        "&dvalue=" + formValue(ctl.attr('value')) +
        "&dchoice=" + formValue(ctl.val());
alert(url);

function formValue(testValue)
{
    return (testValue === undefined ? "" : testValue);
}
```